# How can i create a class with declaration of a variable from another class

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to use [DHT Sensor](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library)

***WifiConfig.h***

```
#include "DHT.h"
class WifiConfig
{
  public:
    WifiConfig();
    std::unique_ptr<DHT> dht;
    void initialize(char const *ssid, char const *psk);

}
```

***WifiConfig.cpp***

```
#include "WifiConfig.h"
WifiConfig::WifiConfig() {}

void WifiConfig::initialize(char const *ssid, char const *psk) {
   dht.reset(new DHT(DHTPin, DHT11));
   dht.readTemperature(); // doesnt work
}
```

What is the right way to use another class in my class this way?

Comment: What about `dht->readTemperature();`?

Comment: *"Doesn't work"?* What does that mean?

Comment: It's very helpful to copy/paste the exact error message you're receiving so we know what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 5):

A smart pointer (like `std::unique_ptr`) is a normal object that has been written to act like a built-in pointer, and they usually wrap a real pointer under the covers. They generally override `operator->()` to provide access to the underlying pointer. This allows users of smart pointers to pretend that they're using real pointers.

So change it to `dht->readTemperature()`

Using the dot operator on a smart pointer gives you access to the members of the smart pointer object itself.

Comment: Thanks, That worked. 
is ```std::unique_ptr<DHT> dht;``` is the right way to use another class in one class?

Comment: It's not the only way, but it's a perfectly valid way.

Comment: how if if the constructor requires params?